# Does anyone know a good PHP CMS built on a MVC framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, content-management-system

Does anyone know of a PHP CMS that is uses a MVC framework to work its magic? I'm looking for something that I can customize the look and feel of the website by using PHP, HTML and CSS while allowing for the content, users and internal categorizing strcuture of the pages to be managed within a backend CMS admin. Preferably something with an ORM, but its not 100% necessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at http://octobercms.com/ based on laravel(php mcv framework)  and support ORM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few : [Apostrophe Now](http://apostrophenow.org/) is built using Symfony, [TomatoCMS](http://www.tomatocms.com/) is based on the Zend Framework, and there's lots more.

Here's a few extra references to Zend Framework based CMSes I collected over the years :
[Centurion Project](http://www.centurion-project.org/), [Recite CMS](http://www.recitecms.com/) and [pimcore](http://www.pimcore.org/). I haven't looked at any of them yet though, just bookmarked them :p.

Edit:

[Apostrophe Now](http://apostrophenow.org/): They've now entirely shifted to Node.

Answer (score 2):

You can see for [`CROOGO`](http://croogo.org/) a cool CMS built in CakePHP(MVC) framework.

Also other is [Silverstrip](http://www.silverstripe.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Drupal fits the MVC perspective, but it basically is divided up the way you describe. Themes can be created applied with PHP modified code that can get you whatever effect you want and is maintained separately.